# How to give vertical space for a multiline title?

Tags: spacing, titles, titling

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{Validation of Numerical Simulation of Fender Tests\par}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{3cm}
\textsf{\huge{\thetitle}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

I want some more spacing between the first line and second line of my title. I tried adding `\vspace`, `\\`, `\newline` after the word 'Beer' but nothing works.

Comment: add `\par` at the end of the title. And remove the pair of braces around it.

Comment: Sorry, forgot: Change `\textsf` to `\sffamily`. btw, you can find more about titlepages: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already loading `titling`, use its methods:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titling}

\pretitle{\begin{center}\linespread{1.5}\huge\sffamily}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vspace{0.5em}}

\begin{document}

\title{Evaluation of Security aspects in a Beer Production company}
\author{Adalbert Uthor}
\date{}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Adjust the value for `\linespread` to suit your needs and wishes.

[image]

If you use the `titlepage` environment, you can use a similar method:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titling}

\begin{document}
\title{Evaluation of Security aspects in a Beer Production company}
\author{Adalbert Uthor}
\date{}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering

\vspace*{\stretch{1}}

{\linespread{1.5}\huge\sffamily\thetitle\par}

\vspace{4ex}

{\Large\theauthor\par}

\vspace{\stretch{3}}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This works, but is not a perfect solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\linespread{5}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{3cm}
\textsf{\huge Evaluation of Security aspects in a Beer\\[.7cm] Production company}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A consistent solution, however, using native KOMA commands would be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setkomafont{title}{\sffamily\huge\linespread{1.5}}
\title{Evaluation of Security aspects in a Beer Production company}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh please don't. This is very very bad practice.

Comment: Yes, that's why I say "not perfect"

Comment: better do `\sffamily\huge the title \par` ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B : I did edit my code based on you previous suggestions to ask you more about it but your last suggestion did the trick. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Good to hear. That solution can be found in the question i linked above. I marked it as a possible duplicate, which it apparently is ;-)

Comment: A bit better, never use `\maketitle` inside `titlepage`-env, second: It's called KOMA, not coma ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A method with changing the `\baselineskip` -- since it is done in a group, it won't hurt outside.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{Theory of Brontosaurs -- their thickness and Thin-Lizzy-Likeness}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\let\origbaselineskip\baselineskip
\begin{center}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.5\origbaselineskip}
\textsf{\huge \thetitle}

\setlength{\baselineskip}{2\origbaselineskip}
\textsf{\huge \thetitle }

\setlength{\baselineskip}{3\origbaselineskip}
\textsf{\huge \thetitle }

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\huge` doesn't take an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use de `setspace` package and use the `spacing` enviroment. For example using this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{3cm}
 \begin{spacing}{3}
  \textsf{\huge{Evaluation of Security aspects in a Beer Production company}}
 \end{spacing}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

I got this:

[image]